# Cmake File COPY across drives

Tags: windows, cmake, copy, drives

The following does not work:

```
cmake file ( copy "C:/pathtofile/file.file" DESTINATION "D:/pathtofile2/file2.file" )
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing using cmake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: copy file from source directory to binary directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799916/cmake-copy-file-from-source-directory-to-binary-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmakes fantastic Configure file system will work. The files can have different names, but basically if it finds any variables that can be expanded by cmake like ${cmake_root_dir} or $ENV{localappdata}, it will edit the file, replace the variables with their values and save it to the new location under the new name. So if there are no variables it just copies.

```
Configure_file( C:/pathtofile/file.file" "D:/pathtofile2/file2.file")
```

If you have cmake style variables in there for whatever reason and you don't want them expanded, use @Only as it will only expand variables surrounded by "@":

```
Configure_file( C:/pathtofile/file.file" "D:/pathtofile2/file2.file" @ONLY)
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states that DESTINATION has to be a directory. Therefore renaming the file does not work this way.

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "C:/pathtofile/file.file" "D:/pathtofile2/file2.file")
```

should work.

Comment: You are 100% correct, however I think configure_file( C:/pathtofile/file.file" "D:/pathtofile2/file2.file") is cooler.

Comment: Do you think that it's unclear code if I have it calling configure_file? or unnecessary processing?

Comment: I don't think so. But I use configure_file only in cases when variable substitutions should be made. The option COPYONLY is crucial to configure_file for your first case. It says: whatever is in the file leave it alone.