# Unconditionally copy file in ${SRC_DIR} for all recipes

Tags: cmake

I have a file called `adhoc.cpp.proto` in `${SRC_DIR}`. I need to copy it to a file named `adhoc.cpp` in `${SRC_DIR}` in preparation for some other tasks. I prefer to create the file if it does not exists, but I'll take an unconditional copy to keep things simple.

According to [Copy file from source directory to binary directory using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34799916/608639) I should be able to use `configure_file(old new COPYONLY)` or `file(COPY old DESTINATION new)`. Neither work for me. `configure_file(old new COPYONLY)` does nothing, and `file(COPY old DESTINATION new)` creates a directory called `new` and puts the file `old` in it.

According to [the `file` command docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html) `GENERATE` may also work. The problem is, I can't figure out how to use it from the docs and I can't find examples of it.

How do I unconditionally copy `${SRC_DIR}/old` to `${SRC_DIR}/new`?

---

In case it is needed, testing is happening on Fedora 28 with:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.11.2
```

But I need this to work back to CMake 2.8, which is what is found in the field for current distros.

---

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt
# <head notes ...>

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.6)
if (${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS "3.0.0")
  project(cryptopp)
  set(cryptopp_VERSION_MAJOR 7)
  set(cryptopp_VERSION_MINOR 0)
  set(cryptopp_VERSION_PATCH 0)
else ()
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
  project(cryptopp VERSION 7.0.0)
  if (NOT ${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS "3.1.0")
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)
  endif ()
endif ()

set(SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

# Create adhoc.cpp from adhoc.cpp.proto.
# configure_file(adhoc.cpp.proto adhoc.cpp COPYONLY)
# file(COPY ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp.proto DESTINATION/${SRC_DIR} adhoc.cpp)
file(COPY ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp.proto DESTINATION ${SRC_DIR} adhoc.cpp)
...
```

---

`configure_file(adhoc.cpp.proto adhoc.cpp COPYONLY)` produces:

```
cmake_build$ rm -rf * && rm -rf ../adhoc.cpp && cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.1
...
# Nothing is copied
cmake_build$ ls ../adhoc*
../adhoc.cpp.proto
```

---

`file(COPY ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp.proto DESTINATION ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp)` creates directories:

```
cmake_build$ rm -rf * && rm -rf ../adhoc.cpp && cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.1
...
# Puts old file in directory
cmake_build$ ls ../adhoc*
../adhoc.cpp.proto

../adhoc.cpp:
adhoc.cpp.proto
```

---

`file(COPY ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp.proto ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp DESTINATION ${SRC_DIR})` fails:

```
cmake_build$ rm -rf * && rm -rf ../adhoc.cpp && cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.1
...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:65 (file):
  file COPY cannot find "/home/test/cryptopp/adhoc.cpp".
```

---

`file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp.proto CONDITION true)` fails, too (as does `CONDITION 1`):

```
cmake_build$ rm -rf * && rm -rf ../adhoc.cpp && cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.1
...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:66 (file):
  file Incorrect arguments to GENERATE subcommand.
```

---

`file(WRITE ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp file(READ ${SRC_DIR}/adhoc.cpp.proto))` creates the file but it does not evaluate the `file(READ ...)` expression:

```
cmake_build$ rm -rf * && rm -rf ../adhoc.cpp && cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.1
...

$ cat ../adhoc.cpp
file(READ/home/test/cryptopp/adhoc.cpp.proto)
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Bernhard - No, it did not work for me. CMake creates a directory with the new filename and then copies the original file into the directory.

Comment: Wait, you want to copy from the source directory into the source directory? Why? That does not make sense to me

Comment: @Bernhard - We are unpacking a template file.

Comment: That does not mean anything to me in this context. One of the reasons to use cmake is to clearly separate source and build. Either unpack into build and compile from there, or unpack it in source before cmake

Comment: @Bernhard - My bad. Let me rephrase... We are trying to copy and rename a file in one operation.

Comment: The thing that I don't get is why the destination is the source directory

Answer (score 1):

You have found the right commands. Both `configure_file` and `file(COPY)` are perfectly capable to do what you want.

For `file(COPY)`, keep in mind that the `DESTINATION` is a directory, not a filename. It will create the directory in case it is does not exists. You are creating a directory `adhoc.cpp` in your source directory. That is why you probably have a `rm -rf ../adhoc.cpp`.

Your `configure_file` seems legit. But, [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/configure_file.html) says that if the destination is a directory, it will place it in there. Maybe you have a conflict with the other things you did.

My recommendation to prevent these things it to always have an out-of-source build, rather than in-source as you have it now. Is `${SRC_DIR}` something you define yourself? Why not `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`? Although in this case I don't think you need to do this anyhow, that's for CMake to figure out.