# use cmake configure_file to copy recursive files

Tags: cmake

I wanna using **configure_file(<input> <output> COPYONLY)**  to copy a specific directory files recursive , I used this command:

```cmake
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res/* ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/res COPYONLY)
```

but I got some errors , How I should use this command for this porpuse? (I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799916/copy-file-from-source-directory-to-binary-directory-using-cmake) too), the Errors:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:86 (configure_file):
> configure_file Problem configuring file

I know that I can use it with file(...) too , but I wanna use configure_file(...):

```cmake
file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/res)
```

Comment: From the cmake documentation of `configure_file` (emphasis mine): *"Copies **an** `<input>` file to **an** `<output>` file .."*

Comment: "I wanna use configure_file(...)" - Then you need to use it for **every** separate file. You could obtain list of files using `file(GLOB)` and iterate over this list with `foreach`.

Comment: There's `execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/res")` which does seem to achieve what you seem to attempt here btw...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use configure_file to copy a folder directly.
The command is about

> copy a file to another location and modify its contents.

It operates on one file only.
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html